# Can I set Content-Type via curl on command-line without adding "boundary=------"?

Tags: curl, http-headers, content-type

I am sending a command-line curl command to a webserver.  The webserver only accepts content of type application/xml or application/json.  My curl command (slightly edited) is:

```
curl -k  --cert certfile --form "fileupload=@test.xml" --cacert cacert.pem https://IP:PORT/v1/all/3131 --header "allowed-domains: foo.net" -H "Content-Type:application/xml"
```

I'm finding that the server rejects this with the following:

```
POST load request has invalid type application/xml; boundary=----------------------------dc1435dd0d36
```

The problem is that the server doesn't recognize

```
"boundary=----------------------------dc1435dd0d36"
```

Is there a way to tell curl not to include that?  Or is this a bug in the server?

I found a related question on SO about this, but it only addressed programs that can set curl options via curl_setopt.  Is there a way to do these things on the command line?  That earlier question was:

[PHP cURL Content-Length and Content-Type wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152165/php-curl-content-length-und-content-type-wrong)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to send `application/xml`, you should use `--data` instead of `--form` which sends `multipart/form-data`. An in your case, it should be the content of the file, not the file itself that you want to send. Like this:

```
curl -k  --cert certfile --data "@test.xml" --cacert cacert.pem https://IP:PORT/v1/all/3131 --header "allowed-domains: foo.net" -H "Content-Type:application/xml"
```

Comment: Thank you- that worked!  I didn't realize that --form would send it as multipart/form-data even if I set the Content-Type explicitly, but it makes sense.

Comment: Also worked for me. I was trying something like option c of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33360009/66372.